# How to start and debug an Outlook Web Add-in from VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, yeoman, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created an Outlook WEB Add-in from Visual Studio. I want to continue with VS Code to develop the project, but how to start it and debug? I stumbled across this articles by Microsoft:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/office

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/creating-office-add-ins-with-any-editor-introducing-yo-office/

Downloaded and installed both node.js and Yeoman and managed to create a new Office project with them, using VS Code. Ok, but how to run already created project with Visual Studio that has kind of different folder structure? I loaded the project with VS Code and when I started debug process and add the following configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\MyAddInWeb\\Login.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:44392/d1234530-8653-45d8-8634-b28355329cee For help,
>   see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached.
>   c:\Users\mydir
>   Workplace\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5
>       Office.initialize = function (reason) {
>       ^
>
> ReferenceError: Office is not defined
>       at c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5:5
>       at Object. (c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:109:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:14)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) Waiting for ReferenceError: Office is not defined Login.js:5
>       at c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5:5
>       at Object. (c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:109:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:14)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)  the debugger to disconnect...

Comment: At this point there is no debugging from VSCode. Edge and IE WebViews only communicate over the PDM debug protocol. This is a legacy protocol that only Visual Studio Express, or greater, can speak